# FreeSwitch mod installation fails

Tags: javascript, voip, freeswitch

I have installed FreeSwitch on mac (OS X Yosemite 10.10.5) and I have to use javascript (mod_v8) for IVR calls. I have followed the steps for mod_v8 activation here: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_v8

1.Uncomment languages/mod_v8 in modules.conf in your src directory (make it always build and install mod_v8)

2.Run 'make mod_v8-install' to make and install just the v8 module

3.Edit conf/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml in your FreeSWITCH™ install directory to load mod_v8

4.In fs_cli, run "load mod_v8"*

However, I get the following error while running make mod_v8-install (Step 2) : 
[error on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrWro.png)

Also should I disable LUA when activating mod_v8?

Comment: can you post complete error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a 'info' type error being generated by the compiler.. Report the issue as a bug to FreeSWITCH?

Or try using the `-i`  flag when compiling - https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html

"Also should I disable LUA when activating mod_v8?"

No :)

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the  from modules.conf.xml after recompiling. Try "reload mod_v8" command in fs_cli. I had the same issue its missing in the freeswitch document.